# How to write user-mode NAT without any binding port?

Tags: sockets, capture, nat, tcp

I would like to make my own user-mode NAT application.

I have the folowing scheme:

> VM2[192.168.**8.2**] ------ [192.168.**8.1**]Win2003[192.168.**9.1**] ------ [192.168.**9.2**]VM1
>
> VM3[192.168.**8.3**] _/
>
> VM4[192.168.**8.4**] _/

1. I'm capturing RAW IP packets on 8.1 and 9.1 interfaces.
2. Some packets from 8.1 are transfered to 9.1 interface this way: 8.2->9.2 replaced by 9.1->9.2
3. Some packets from 9.1 are transfered to 8.1 interface this way: 9.2->9.1 replaced by 9.2->8.2

My application does not bind any ports at all - it is only capturing from interfaces.

I saw this scenario:

1. 8.2->9.2 translated to 9.1->9.2 contains SYN flag
2. 9.2->9.1 translated to 9.2->8.2 containt SYN+ACK flags
3. **And** step 2 contains 9.1->9.2 with RST flag...

Windows Server 2003 resets my NATed connection. I don't want to bind any ports at all.

How can I handle this?

**UPDATE:**

user1202136, how is it possible to:

> Use Windows Firewall to block RST packets from the ports your
> user-space NAT uses.

without writing own NDIS driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [TCP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) specification, a RST is always sent when an ACK (or SYN+ACK) is received on a port which is not bound to any process. This is done to ensure that node crashes can be reliably detected.

In your case, it is the TCP/IP implementation in Windows Server 2003 that generates the RST packet. You should either prevent the ACK from reaching the TCP layer or block the RST from reaching the wire. You could try doing this in several ways:

1. Disable TCP (but not IP) on your interfaces.
2. Use Windows Firewall to block RST packets from the ports your user-space NAT uses.
3. (Not sure this is working) Use Windows Firewall to block all TCP packets to the ports your user-space NAT uses. I am afraid this would also block packets from reaching your RAW socket.

Comment: +1, correct specification, correct way to filter out dubious `RST` packets. Oh, I've fond memories of when people first started doing this to prevent their ISPs from killing their downloads... \*shakes cane\*

Comment: ...or if you are willing to add a non-usermode component, you can create an intermediate NDIS driver to drop the RST packetz you don't want the TCP stack(s) to see.